# why the sizeof arr[][3] is 36

Tags: arrays, sizeof

```
int arr[][3] = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70};
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(arr));
```

sorry it's my first time here, this is my first problem that I can't solve please forgive my grammar
why is the output of this in my compiler is 36? when it's only have 7 elements, and 7 * 4 = 28, thank in advance for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared an array of 3-tuples, and it contains three such tuples:

```
{10, 20, 30},
{40, 50, 60},
{70,  _,  _},  // _ is unspecified and will be 0
```

In total, this is 9 ints, and `9*sizeof(int) == 36`

If you declared an `int[]` instead of an `int[][3]`, it would indeed have 7 ints and a sizeof 28.